# Is there a non-hook alternative for the React Material-UI makeStyles() function that works for class Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Im using the makeStyles() function in material-UI's react library, and am getting the following error

**Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.**

Below is an example of the kind of code I am using.

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  textField: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  dense: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  menu: {
    width: 200,
  },
}));

class Demo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
      <TextField
        className={classes.textField}
      >
        <MenuItem>Demo</MenuItem>
      </TextField>
    )
  }
}
```

I know the error is being thrown because I'm trying to use makeStyles() in my class component (As shown above).

However, I'm curious if there is an alternative to makeStyles() for class components in Material-UI's react library, or what the syntax would be to get the functionality of make-styles in a class component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`makeStyles` is just a `high order function` (returns a hook) to apply styles in functional components. You can always use `withStyles`, which is an `HOC` for the exact same purpose and works for both class an functional components

```
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/styles'

const styles = {
   root: {
     background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)'
   }
};

class Component extends React.Component{
    render(){
        const { classes } = this.props
        return <div className={classes.foo} />
    }
}
export default withStyles(styles)(Component)
```

Comment: Thank god! Hooks are terrible!

Comment: Why do you think so @SacWebDeveloper?

Comment: Hook lifecycle patterns are not explicit like component lifecycle (componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, etc.), magic hooks make code uglier to read/write and generally harder to follow the logic, you also have to learn a bunch of weird non-standard functions (useCallback, useEffect, etc.). Want to compare previous props or state, easy with classes, with hooks you have to use some ref hack. Moving to hooks assumes everyone likes functional programming over object-oriented. OOP is more widely used and developers coming from Android, iOS, C++, Java, etc can make more sense of classes.

Comment: I've tried hooks and I absolutely hate them. Never going to use them. They are just a fad anyhow. Hooks are a joke, a serious misstep in the wrong direction and should be deprecated. Much like the debacle that is TypeScript, our team has wasted countless hours dealing with hook oddities and it's learning curves. Facebook should admit they were misguided in forcing this on developers and fix their mistake before too many codebases get further gummed up.