# Material-UI Typescript How to make create style instance from makeStyle() in a component class

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

makeStyle() from Material-UI works fine, however I moved my function component to a class component and now it causes an error because it violates the Rule Of Hooks for React (calls React.useContext())

How can I get the same result of makeStyle() while using a class component? It seems Material-UI's documentation assumes that all components should be function components as I am unable to find barely any class component examples or information.

I've tried withStyles(style)(App) with no luck, as it causes an error that states many properties are incompatible which I find odd.

Since I am using Typescript, does my prop interface need something or do I need to do something such as

```js
const Component = withStyles(styles)(({classes}) =>{
    return <div className={classes.foo} /<
})
```

for withStyle() to work?
Reference: [Is there a non-hook alternative for the React Material-UI makeStyles() function that works for class Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58441802/is-there-a-non-hook-alternative-for-the-react-material-ui-makestyles-function)

Comment: The non-hook alternative is `withStyles` which works on both functional and class based components. Your code should work as it is. Your problem probably lies elsewhere. Could you please post a sandbox and/or snippet of the problem?

Comment: oh! It's my own answer hahahahah

Comment: See the documentation here: https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/#usage-of-withstyles.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

[Ryan Cogswell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7495930/ryan-cogswell) answer was the best answer. To quote:

```
See the documentation here: material-ui.com/guides/typescript/#usage-of-withstyles
```

worked phenomenally. Thank you :)